# fsolve TypeError error at scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, typeerror

I have couple of connected functions, and since they are very complicated and huge, I don't want to bore you with the exact mathematical code. I did my best to shorten my calculations to demonstrate here. You can pick any 5x5 Hermitian matrix at the first function. Here is the summary of code:

```
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np
import scipy as sp

def matrix(x, alpha, beta):
    mat = #Some 5x5 matrix which depend on the parameters x, alpha, beta.
    return np.sort(LA.eigvals(mat)) #it returns an array with 5 elements.

def integrand(x, alpha, beta):
    #Some mathematical calculation which uses the function above, it returns a scalar. 
    h = 0.0000000001;
    #The routine below is for taking the derivative with respect to beta
    mm = np.imag(matrix(x,alpha,beta + 1j*h))/h
    return (mm[0]**2 + mm[2]**2)

def integrate(alpha, beta):
    return quad(integrand,0,600, args = (alpha,beta))[0]-1

y0 = 1.5    
beta = 2

fsolve(integrate,y0,args = (beta))
```

And fsolve gives me so many errors, they are all the same:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

The error is due to some function gives NaN.

```
/usr/local/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.pyc in _assertFinite(*arrays)
214 def _assertFinite(*arrays):
215     for a in arrays:
--> 216         if not (isfinite(a).all()):
217             raise LinAlgError("Array must not contain infs or NaNs")
218 

TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I guess this is due to data type of the number is not sufficient. I suspect it is due to the last line at the integrate function:

```
quad(...)[0]-1
```

I am new to Python world, any help or workaround is quite appreciated. Is there a way to set the data type throughout the calculations?

Edit for simplified code:

```
from scipy.integrate import quad
from numpy import linalg as LA
import numpy as np
from pylab import *

from scipy.integrate import odeint
from scipy.integrate import ode
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


#This routine is for the matrix, and the routine returns the eigenvalues
def matrix(r, theta, delta1, delta2):

    mat = np.array([[r**2-1,r*np.cos(theta),0,delta1],[r*np.cos(theta),r**2 - 1, -delta1,0],[0,-delta2,-r**2+1,-r*np.cos(theta)],[delta2,0,-r*np.cos(theta),-r**2+1]])

    return np.sort(LA.eigvals(mat))[2:4]

#This routine takes the derivatives of eigenvalues with respect to the parameter delta. I set delta1 = delta2.
def deriv(r, theta, delta):

    h = 0.00000000001

    return np.imag(matrix(r, theta, delta, delta+h*1j))/h

#This is the integrand that we need to integrate over r and theta
def integrand(theta,r, beta, delta):

    ee = matrix(r, theta, delta, delta)

    dd = deriv(r, theta, delta)

    return (np.tanh(0.5*beta*ee[0])*dd[0]+np.tanh(0.5*beta*ee[1])*dd[1])*r*r*np.sin(theta)

#Just integrate over theta
def polarint(y,r,beta,delta):

    return quad(integrand,0,np.pi,args = (r,beta,delta))[0]

#Instead of integrating directly over r, solve the differential equation.
#Lambda is the range of r.
def givesclen(delta, beta, lam):
    y0 = 0
    t_out = np.linspace(0, lam, 2500);
    rt = odeint(polarint,y0,t_out,args=(beta,delta))
    temp = (rt[-1]/delta)/(4*np.pi**2)-t_out[-1]/(2*np.pi**2)
    return temp[0]

#The goal is to find the delta; given sl, lam, beta
#Such that the result of the integration is equal to sl
def equationgap(delta, beta, lam,sl):
    return givesclen(delta, beta, lam)*4*np.pi - sl

#Test if the equationgap works, the result should be close to zero!
equationgap(.5,40,500,.1744)

#Now use the fsolve function should find the delta to be .5!
beta = 50
lam = 600
sl = 0.174
mu = 1
fsolve(equationgap,.6,args = (beta, lam, sl))
```

Comment: Please always paste the full error traceback, not just the last line or just the error message. The error message indicates you're passing something that is not a matrix to `LA.eigvals`.

Comment: I don't know if this is the problem, but you'll get that error if `mat` is an array with dtype `object`.  E.g. `np.linalg.eigvals(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]], dtype=object))`.  Just before you call `eigvals`, print `type(mat)` and, if it is a numpy array, print `mat.dtype`.

Comment: Thank you for your replies. @pv, the error messages are all the same. The fsolve function calls other functions numerous times and these error messages are all very lengthy.

Comment: @Warren, I have called type(mat) and the return was <type 'numpy.ndarray'>. And the dtype of the matrix was float64. I guess this error message is due to a number gets very small, such that float64 cannot handle it and puts NaN. I don't know how to workaround though...

Comment: The error does not say there are nans involved.  The error occurs in `isfinite(a)`, which is specifically designed to check for nan and inf.  It would help if you could post a minimal, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can copy and run ourselves.  Try to make the example as simple as possible while still generating the error.

Comment: @Warren, I have added my code with explanations. Error is similar.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser, I have corrected a syntax error.